# how to place the chart in the centre while using django-chartit?

Tags: javascript, python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, highcharts

I want to place the chart in the web's centre. But i found that whatever i did the chart just stay there stick to the web's left side. Here's my code:

models.py

```
class User_Data(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    click_times = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

views.py's code is below. I just follow the course which is  http://chartit.shutupandship.com And i really got the chart.

```
def userdata_chart_view(request):

    userdata = \
        DataPool(
            series=
            [{'options': {
                'source': User_Data.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)},
                'terms': [
                    'user',
                    'word',
                    'click_times']}
            ])

    cht = Chart(
        datasource= userdata,
        series_options =
            [{'options':{
                'type': 'column',
                'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
                'word': [
                    'click_times']},
            }],
        chart_options=
        {'title': {'text': '搜索频率'},
         'xAxis': {'title': {'text': '词条'}},
         'yAxis': {'title': {'text': '频率'}},
         }
    )

    content1 = {'user_data_chart': cht}
    return render(request, 'yigu/charts.html', content1)
```

And here's the charts.html

```
{% extends 'yigu/base_charts.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="charts" style="width:450px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't know how to figure the centre problem, although i have already searched solution by google. Anyone could help me?

Comment: Look like you are using Bootstrap, this might be helpful: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) has 12 cols. You only define 4 cols.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="charts" style="width:450px">
          &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```